# STM8L151 UART software

Tags: uart, stm8

I am new in STM programming and I want to do a simple UART communication but I don't know where to start.Can somebody send a tutorial for stm8l or a full code would be better so I can examine it.

Thx.

Schematics :

[image: stm8]

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'm afraid it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step in a question but not provide tutorials. Sorry, that's not what the site's about. Again, a warm welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with STM8, but with STM32 there is STM32CubeMX, where you can configure your code and find examples. It seems that there is [version for STM8 too](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm8cubemx.html).

Once you download it, it should have some examples (they should be in STM8Cube folder in C:/Users/your user, if it is similar to STM32CubeMX) and you would be able to generate your starting code, it should be similar as for STM32CubeMX, which has a lot of tutorials in the internet.